# Decimal data type in sql server rounding up number to zero

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in table x which is a decimal type : decimal(21,4)

When I enter the number 0.00873 it changes it to 0.0000
Can anyone explain why is that happening and what can I do to save the numbers of the nature I stated above?

Comment: how you enter the number? show us the code

Comment: it is being entered through the UI. But when it gets saved in the database it changes to 0.0000

Comment: When you say UI do you mean management studio or a custom UI? Also - is it possible you have different decimal point settings so you use comma but think you write period? Is there a trigger on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Just an assumption (I think in this case there can be no solution at all because nobody can explain what is this "THAT" you mention what is happening)

I think there is nothing about SQL Server. Probably you need to look inside UI about the reasons of this error.
SQL code below shows how the decimal number can be zeroed because of internal type inconsistency - when original data between the input and output are stored in the less-precise type.

```
declare
    @dec decimal(21, 4),
    @int int;

set @dec = 0.00873;
set @int = @dec;

select @dec [original]
, @int [integer]
, cast(@int as decimal(21, 4)) [cast_back_to_decimal]
```

Result

```
original    integer cast_back_to_decimal
----------------------------------------
0.0087      0       0.0000
```